# Possible bug in safari when calculating negative percentage margin

Tags: jquery, animation, safari

Please consider this piece of js code:

```
function scroll(){
    $('.container').css('marginLeft', '-50%');
    $('.container').animate({'marginLeft': 0}, 300);
}​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aSXBL/3/

There is a strange behavior in Safari - the animation happen from 'right to left' instead of 'left to right'. After some analyze I found that jQuery animates starting with positive margin values in this case.

Do you think it should be considered as a bug or its just a specific 'feature' of Safari? What a workaround may help in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to calculate the pixels first and then set it to the div to see how it animates?

Comment: @JoeFletch, yes I tried and it worked well. I mean if pixels are set, it works well. But there is a bug with percentage values.

Comment: Is that the answer that you are looking for? Or do you just want to know if it is a _feature_?

Comment: @JoeFletch I'm making a template and it would be perfect form me to use percents. And also I want to ensure that it is a bug so that i could send it to support in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug - percentages returning unexpected results (not only related to the animate function in fact). See:

```
console.log($('.container').css('marginLeft'));
// 10px as expected
$('.container').css('marginLeft', '-50%');
// object visually moved as expected
console.log($('.container').css('marginLeft'));
// this outputs 300px in Safari
```

Comment: I can confirm the above, had a problem using border-radius with 50% on safari, it didn't work and had to use a em value instead.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll sent it to support. Hope it is fixed in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The fix is using CSS Transitions for modern browsers and jQuery animate for the rest. I used modernizr to decide which was served. This makes Safari 5 use CSS, thus avoiding the issue.

```
if( !Modernizr.csstransitions ){
  $('#gallery .slides').animate({"margin-left":'-200%'}, 750);
} else {
  $('#gallery .slides').css({"margin-left":'-200%'});
}
            }
```